# How can I export to file the User Information List for a site collection?

Tags: 2007, site-collection, export

I would like to export the User Information List to a file including the ID of each user.  It doesn't matter if the solution is in C#/PowerShell/SharePoint UI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Go to "Site Settings -> Users and Permissions -> People and groups"
2. Click on the "Settings" menu and "List Settings"
3. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click on the view that you want to export.
4. Copy the url and in particular the List and View IDs

> http://sitename/_layouts/ViewEdit.aspx?List=**%7B64DAB4AC%2DD043%2D4DA4%2D85C7%2D9D4521C3F4CC%7D**&View=**%7B0FAE8D90%2D59D5%2D48F4%2DA54E%2DF02333777C7F%7D**&Source=%252F%255Flayouts%252Flistedit%252Easpx%253FList%253D64dab4ac%252Dd043%252D4da4%252D85c7%252D9d4521c3f4cc%2526Source%253DhttpFlayouts%25252Fpeople%25252Easpx%25253FMembershipGroupId%25253D6
>
> Go to the following url "http://**[sitename]**/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=**[LISTID]**&View=**[VIEWID]**&CacheControl=1" replacing sitename, listid, and viewid with your own information.
>
> When opening this in the browser you will get a save to excel option and from there you just have to open the file.
>
> I got my solution from [Explore the SharePoint](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/03/export-sharepoint-user-groups-in-excel.html) and [SharePoint Blogs](http://sharepointsearch.com/cs/blogs/sharepointblogs/archive/2007/10/03/export-user-information-to-excel-using-quot-export-to-spreadsheet-quot-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx).